# Effective books for learning the intricacies of business application development?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, application-planning

I am a self taught "developer". I use the term loosely because I only know enough to make myself dangerous.  I have no theory background, and I only pick up things to get this little tool to work or make that control do what I want.

That said, I am looking for some reading material that explains some of the theory behind application development especially from a business standpoint.  Really I need to understand what all of these terms that float around really talk about.  Business Logic Layer, UI abstraction level and all that.  Anyone got a reading list that they feel helped them understand this stuff?  I know how to code stuff up so that it works.  It is not pretty mostly because I don't know the elegant way of doing it, and it is not planned out very well (I also don't know how to plan an application).

Any help would be appreciated.  I have read a number of books on what I thought was the subject, but they all seem to rehash basic coding and what-not.

This doesn't have to be specific to VB.NET or WPF (or Entity Framework) but anything with those items would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most people would recommend [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) by Steve McConnell as the first book to read on putting some good software together.

Answer (score 3):

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com)'s [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to some of the others (and after Code Complete), try [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).